# switching between two Anchor Panes

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm new to JavaFX and I need to switch between two Anchor Panes not having menubar, but signup button in anchorpane itself,it should switch to registration form form sign-in form  I'm using Scene Builder to generate the .FXML files,

My question is how to do this in a simple way?[loginForm with signup button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFnxE.jpg)

[image]

**ERRRO IS**

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)  at
>   javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)  at
>   javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)   at
>   javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)  at
>   javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)  at
>   javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)  at
>   javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)  at
>   javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)    at
>   javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)  at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)    at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)  at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)     ...
>   48 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not
>   set.  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2434)    at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)     at
>   localmart.view.AuthController.Register(AuthController.java:22)    ... 58
>   more

**Main.java**

```
package localmart.view;
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    private Stage primaryStage;
    private AnchorPane mainLayout;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("Local Mart");
        showMainView();

    }

    private void showMainView() {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/login.fxml")); // login
                                                                        // form
        try {
            mainLayout = loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(mainLayout);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

> controller.java

```
package localmart.view;

    import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class AuthController {
    @FXML AnchorPane anchorPane;

@FXML
private void RegisterStage() throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("reg.fxml"));
    Pane registerPane = (Pane) fxmlLoader.load();
    try {
        anchorPane.getChildren().clear();
        anchorPane.getChildren().add(registerPane);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}   
}
```

my question how to load register form in main.java and on click signup button i need to switch registerform

i set controller,onaction,fx:id to login.fxml

Comment: Share your fxml file and what do you mean by switching? Hide the signup  anchorpane and show registerform??? Or keep both visible?

Comment: i designed two fxml file one is for login form and other register form...if i clicked signup button which is in login form stage(window) it should open register form window

Comment: So actually you want to load a different fxml file in the same scene, right?
Currently you are calling same method `showSignUp()` in the button action which loads the same fxml in the scene. So if you are trying what i said, first load the login fxml and load the register form in button action

Comment: first its loading login form.. how to load register form in main.java. can u help me in this... actually i didnt defined code for showSignUp method in main.java.

Comment: Do you want to load the register form in the same window, or in a new window?

Comment: same window @IR Emon..thanking you advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have an `AnchorPane` in `login.fxml` which will be the parent and will be the container of all other elements and i set `anchorPane` as the `id` of that `Anchorpane` (you can choose yours). After doing it, you just need to  add these code section in your controller class

```
@FXML AnchorPane anchorPane;

@FXML
private void RegisterStage() throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("reg.fxml"));
    Pane registerPane = (Pane) fxmlLoader.load();
    try {
        anchorPane.getChildren().clear();
        anchorPane.getChildren().add(registerPane);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Replace the `reg.fxml` by your desired `fxml` you want to load.

Comment: i updated my question top.. i got error after changing what u said exactly

Comment: i put folder structure above in my question

Comment: Is it crashing on the launch or crashes after sign up button press?? And as the controller class and fxml in the same package, you should use `FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Register.fxml"));`

Comment: pleasure's mine to able to help you

Comment: after getting into registration form..i need to goback to sign-in form on button click(sign-in)..the same code will do na...@IR Emon

Comment: No. Because you already cleared all other children of the anchorPane.